# I need to create a list by extracting information out of a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have written a code which extracts all running public IP's from AWS . This returns the data in the form of a dict. The code runs as follows:

```
for region in regions:
    instance_information = {}
    ip_dict = {}
    client = boto3.client('ec2',aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,region_name=region,)
    addresses_dict = client.describe_addresses().get('Addresses')

    for address in addresses_dict:

        if address.get('InstanceId'):
            instance_information[address['InstanceId']] = [address.get('PublicIp')]
         #   print  instance_information

    dex_dict = client.describe_tags().get('Tags')
    for dex in dex_dict:
        if instance_information.get(dex['ResourceId']):
            instance_information[dex['ResourceId']].append(dex.get('Value'))
    for instance in instance_information:

        if len(instance_information[instance]) == 2:
            ip_dict[instance_information[instance][0]] = instance_information[instance][1]
        else:
            ip_dict[instance_information[instance][0]] = ''
    print (json.dumps(instance_information,indent=4))
    print type(instance_information)
```

This gives the result as :

```
{
    "i-cqa1ea32": [
        "22.40.13.171", 
        "Prod LB", 
        "pdx-ms-prod--lb01"
    ], 
    "i-b86adf671": [
        "12.6.1.3", 
        "pdx-trial-LBi", 
        "HAProxy Server", 
        "us-west-2", 
        "pdx-cloud-trial", 
        "subnet-d8e1af", 
        "us-west-2b"
    ], 
    "i-47dabsa1": [
        "12.5.124.146", 
        "SDL Exclusive LB", 
        "pdx01-ms-prod-sdl-lb02"
    ], 
    .
    . 
    .
```

Now this is of a type `dict` , i need to extract the IP , the tag name and the region, so basically a mapping from the above data as

```
IP , Tag Name, Region
```

ex :

```
['12.1.1.1','pdx-dev-server','us,west-1']
['12.1.1.3','pdx-dev-server1','ap-southeast-1']
..
..
```

But some of the dict objects aren't having a region etc. How can i create a `list` out of the above data , and i need to actually pass (return) the IP addresses to another code .
Please HELP

Comment: [`dict.items`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) should get you started. I see you're using python 2, so that'll be a list of `(key, value)` pairs. Use `dict.iteritems`, if you wish to iterate over those and perform data extraction.

Comment: please give an example as to what the desired output should look like. What's the tag name for example?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis , Updated in question , please note that i need to pass the IP address to another function also

Comment: @IljaEverilä Did you mean something like `ip_list = [i[0]  for i in instance_information.values()]`

Comment: We don't have no idea about your `Tag Name`, `Region`. Please Explain in detail.

Comment: @PythonFreak yeah, that will work for the IPs provided they are the first item in your values list. But you cant do it like that for the tags and region.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis i understand what you mean , but how can i combine the tags and the region ? i mean i need a mapping , see the example i just pasted

Comment: @RahulKP : Look at the example , tag is the Name someone gave to a instance on AWS console , and regions is the availability zone , see the example

Comment: @PythonFreak Is there any common behavior. I mean in the position ? `IP` comes always first. Like that.

Comment: @PythonFreak The second entry in your dict (key = "i-b86adf671") for example, has too possible regions as i see it ("us-west-2" & "us-west-2b"). So my question is what are your criteria? Searching for "us-" in the strings? And similarly is the tag the string with "pdx" in it?

Comment: @RahulKP : Ues the IP's are always first i.e `i[0]`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis , nope , i think the criteria is not "us-" but actually to know the array position example `i[3]` represents the region

Comment: @PythonFreak You have to find out the relation of others. Else you have to check while creating the dict.

Comment: `i[0]` is IP , `i[`1]` is TAG , `i[3]` is region , now how to combine this is another List ?not a dict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i[0] is indeed IP, i[1] is Tag and i[3] is Region, you can use this function:

```
def dict_to_list(dict_in):
    ip_list = [i[0] for i in dict_in.values()]
    tag_list = [i[1] for i in dict_in.values()]
    region_list = []
    for i in dict_in.values():
        try:
            region_list.append(i[3])
        except:
            region_list.append("")
    combined_result = list(zip(ip_list, tag_list, region_list))
    return combined_result
```